# Can you re-render vega-lite chart without terminating the old one?

Tags: vega, vega-lite

I know there's some streaming models and other smart ways to update the chart.

But is it possible to do even simpler, just call `vegaEmbed(element, vegaSpec)` on the same element multiple times, so the new chart will replace the old one?

It works, but I wonder if there's some memory leaks or if you need somehow properly terminate the old graph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Vega view API offers a `finalize()` method for exactly this: to be called when a chart is no longer needed, in order to prevent memory leaks. See https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/api/view/#view_finalize

Once you call this, it should be safe to overwrite the old chart.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how can I get the reference to `view` from `vegaEmbed`?

Comment: The vega-embed docs show how you can access the view object in the result returned by ``vegaEmbed``: https://github.com/vega/vega-embed#basic-example